# Форма не передает GET- и POST-запросы.

Tags: post, php, html, get

Есть форма, которая должна передавать данные в php-обработчик, который отошлет их в БД.
Сначала пробовал передавать POST-запросом. Но постоянно страница обработчика выдавала 500-ю ошибку. Потом попробовал GET, страница открылась, но в адресной строке переменных не было.

```
<form id="form_298029" class="appnitro" method="get" action="newprofile.php">
  <div class="form_description">
    <h2>Добавление новой анкеты</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li id="li_1">
      <label class="description" for="element_1">Имя</label>
      <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255"
        value="" />
      </div>
      <p class="guidelines" id="guide_1">
        <small>Введите имя</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="li_2">
      <label class="description" for="element_2">Фамилия</label>
      <div>
        <input id="element_2" name="surname" class="element text medium" type="text"
        maxlength="255" value="" />
      </div>
      <p class="guidelines" id="guide_2">
        <small>Введите фамилию</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="li_3">
      <label class="description" for="element_3">Отчество</label>
      <div>
        <input id="element_3" name="middle" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255"
        value="" />
      </div>
      <p class="guidelines" id="guide_3">
        <small>Введите отчество</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="li_6">
      <label class="description" for="element_6">Класс</label>
      <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_6" name="klass">
          <option value="1">8</option>
          <option value="2">9</option>
          <option value="3">10</option>
          <option value="4" selected="selected">11</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <p class="guidelines" id="guide_6">
        <small>Выберите класс</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="li_7">
      <label class="description" for="element_7">Пол</label>
      <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_7" name="gender">
          <option value="1" selected="selected">Мужской</option>
          <option value="2">Женский</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <p class="guidelines" id="guide_7">
        <small>Выберите пол</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="li_4">
      <label class="description" for="element_4">Email</label>
      <div>
        <input id="element_4" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255"
        value="" />
      </div>
      <p class="guidelines" id="guide_4">
        <small>Введите email</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="li_8">
      <label class="description" for="element_8">Контактный телефон</label>
      <div>
        <input id="element_8" name="phone" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255"
        value="" />
      </div>
      <p class="guidelines" id="guide_8">
        <small>Введите ваш контактный телефон Пример: 89030123456</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="298029" />
      <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit"
      value="Добавить анкету в базу" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Форму то выложите.

Comment: форму покажите то?

Comment: а лучше уберите форму и покажите код обработчика, ошибка в нем.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка 500 "Internal Server Error" возникает в случае невозможности запуска скрипта, который вы разместили на сервере, в случае ошибок в скрипте, а также в случае когда вы поместили неправильную инструкцию в файл .htaccess. Этот список причин возникновения ошибки 500 не конечный, есть еще масса причин, по которым может возникнуть ошибка 500. Однако, упомянутые три случая встречаются наиболее часто.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего проблемы на стороне сервера, посмотрите логи самого сервера, возможно найдете свою проблему.

Comment: проблемы в мозге еще могут быть)

Comment: Остроумно.

Comment: Ошибка 500 - либо тяжкая ошибка в скрипте (переполнение буфера, попытка чтения чего-то недоступного, неоднозначный синтаксис), либо сбой сервера. Если часто - значит, первое. Таки да, источник таких проблем почти всегда в мозге. Алсо, форматируйте код по-нормальному и включите все уровни ошибок - `error_reporting`, `display_errors`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка кроется либо на стороне сервера, либо, что вероятнее, в файле **.htaccess** - если можно, его в студию.